# Create json object with property as an int

Tags: javascript

I am creating a json object like this in javascript

```
data = {
    Days: $('#DayValue').val()
}
```

The output of  `JSON.stringify(data)` is

```
{
 Days : '12'
}
```

How do i remove the quotes around 12 ?

Answer (score 2):

parse it to an int...

```
Days: parseInt($('#DayValue').val())
```

or simply coerce it:

```
Days: +$('#DayValue').val()
```